# SQL - compare rows without cusors

Tags: t-sql

I have a temporary table with the following columns --

```
id              int identity(1,1)   NOT NULL
startDate       dateteime           NOT NULL
endDate         dateteime
amount          decimal(18,8)       NOT NULL
```

I need to run a query such that I get one value of column amount back from it.

- if the max. `startDate` is <= today, then the amount corresponding to that row.
- if min. `startDate` is >= today , then the amount corresponding to that row.
- if we have rows with `startDates` lesser than, equal and greater than today, then the row with `startDate` closest to <= today, should be the one whose amount should be chosen. If the closest `startDate`(<=) to today has an `endDate` less than today, the choose amount of the row, with `startDate` next to the former.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You search the closest startDate. You can only order the table and then limit the resultset! Check this out:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

DECLARE @t TABLE (
    id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL, 
    startDate datetime NOT NULL,
    endDate datetime, 
    amount decimal(18,8)  NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @t (id, startDate, endDate, amount)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '01.01.2009', NULL, 1.221)
INSERT INTO @t (id, startDate, endDate, amount)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '01.03.2009', NULL, 1.221)
INSERT INTO @t (id, startDate, endDate, amount)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '01.10.2011', NULL, 1.22)
INSERT INTO @t (id, startDate, endDate, amount)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '21.04.2011', NULL, 221)
INSERT INTO @t (id, startDate, endDate, amount)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '11.06.2011', NULL, 199221)
INSERT INTO @t (id, startDate, endDate, amount)
    VALUES(NEWID(), '01.01.2009', NULL, 1221)

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @t
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(day, startDate, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: thanks Benjamin, but when i ran your query with your data, it showed me the row with startDate as 6/11/2011, which should have been 4/21/2011, which is closest from today(5/19/2011). had the trow with startDate 4/21 had an endDate less than today say 5/15/2011, then 6/11/2011 should have been the right answer.

Comment: mh but between 11. June and today (19. May) is only 23 days and between 21. April and today (19. May) 28 days. How that additional endDate logic works? in my opinion endDate null = "future open" endDate.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through your question it appears that you just want to select the row where the `startDate` is the closest to the current day.

I think this should give you that, if not please clarify your requirements further. Maybe by adding some sample data and expected output.

```
Select Top 1 *
From YourTable
Where startDate = IsNull(
                (Select Max(startDate) from #t where startdate <= getdate()),
                    (Select Min(startDate) from #t where startdate >= getdate())
                        )
```

Comment: thanks Barry for answer, but there's a small miss on one ocassion. when the closest startDate to TODAY has an endDate less than TODAY, then the next row, if exists should be the one. for example - if today is 5/19 and i have 2 rows - one with startDate 5/10 and endDate 5/17 and the secondRow with startDate 5/22, then it would be the second row. maybe a small fix to your sql would help.